# Code removes stopwords but Word2vec still creates wordvector for stopword?

Tags: python, nltk, gensim, stop-words

I have a code that loads a file, strips each sentence and then removes some stopwords and returns the tokens.

So far so good.. If I include a `print()` statement or do a simple example, I see that stopwords are removed BUT..
when I run the sentences in my word2vec model, the model still creates a wordvector for stopwords like 'the' .. is there an error in my code??

```
class Raw_Sentences(object):

    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname
    def __iter__(self):
        for file in file_loads: # list with the according file names e.g. 'Users/file1.txt'
                       with open(file,'r', buffering=20000000, encoding='utf-8') as t:     
                for sentence in tokenizer.tokenize(t.read().replace('\n', ' ').lower()):
                    sent = remove_stopwords(sentence)
                    print(sent)
                    yield gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(sent, deacc=True)
```

Then I run:

```
sentences = Raw_Sentences(directory)
num_features = 200  
min_word_count = 2 
num_workers = cpu_count()
context_size = 4  
downsampling = 1e-5  
seed = 2 

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences,
                               sg=1, #skip-gram
                               seed=seed,
                               workers=num_workers,
                               size=num_features,
                               min_count=min_word_count,
                               window=context_size,
                               sample=downsampling)     

model.most_similar('the')
```

and it returns similar words.. But the word 'the' should have been removed...

crying out loud

`remove_stopwords` is a gensim function `from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import remove_stopwords`  which takes a set of stopwords `stoplist = set(stop_words)` and removes them `def remove_stopwords(s):       ## del 
    s = utils.to_unicode(s)
    return " ".join(w for w in s.split() if w not in stoplist)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your corpus doesn't contain any instances of `'thé'`? (If it did, that might not be removed by `remove_stopwords()`, but then when passed through `simple_preprocess(..., deacc=True)` the accent-removal would convert it to plain `'the'`.)

Note also that lots of published `Word2Vec` work doesn't bother to remove stop words. The `sample` downsampling will already thin out the occurrences of any very-common words, without needing any fixed list of stop-words.

So even if your code is debugged, that entire stop-word-removal step may be an unnecessary source of complication & fragility in your code.

Comment: I checked again and `the` should be without accents like `é`. Its strange that other words like `were` (also in stopwords) are indeed removed, (but for example `of` is also not removed).. I tried it again using `yield nltk.word_tokenize(remove_stopwords(sentence))` but same result.. also I tried it with just a part of a file and applied `remove_stopwords()` to the according string and indeed stopwords are removed.. but not within the generator.. or better to say: not when I train the model and call the wordvector for some of the stopwords..

Comment: You should construct a single minimal & complete example - such as the output of your generator & tokenizing-code on a single file sufficient to show the problem – to add to your question. (As one strategy for achieving that: write a test that successfully detects when an undesired stop-word is in the value your generator is about to `yield`. When that happens, log exactly what the input to `remove_stopwords()` was. Strip your data down to just that input & examine carefully.) That exercise will probably be enough to reveal what's going wrong.

Comment: As it stands, there are surely missing details from your example. The same `remove_stopwords()` code *won't* behave differently inside a generator, so something else in your IO/tokenization/etc must be different vs your outside-generator test. (&, separate from the visible symptom, your generator is kind of inefficient & awkward: reading giant chunks, then tokenizing, then turning back into a string for `remove_stopwords()`, which internally `split()`s then re-concatenates into a string again, just to be re-tokenized.) And remember: lots of word2vec work doesn't bother removing stop-words.